# R: transpose a series to a matrix with ignoring remains

Tags: r

Matlab can do this task. I cannot get it right so far by using matrix(), t(), and reShape().

My intention is to transpose a series to a matrix of fixed 10 rows and the number of column varies based on the length of the data series. If these are some remains left, they can be discarded.

For example:

```
Row #1     1   2   3   4
Row #2     5   6   7   8
Row #3     9  10  11  12
Row #4    13  14  15  16
Row #5    17  18  19  20
Row #6    21  22  23  24
Row #7    25  26  27  28
Row #8    29  30  31  32
Row #9    33  34  35  36
Row #10   37  38  39  40
```

If there are any remains left (i.e, 41~49), these data can be just discarded.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show specifically what the input and output matrices should look like?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I think you are asking for. A vector of arbitrary length and data. To be turned into a matrix with nrow 10 and ncol based on data length.

```
#your series of arbitrary length
data = 1:49

#calculate number of columns based on length
col = as.integer(length(data)/10)

#max index
maxIndx = 10*col

#create and transpose matrix
yourMtx = t(matrix(data[0:maxIndx],col,10))

#your matrix
>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    2    3    4
 [2,]    5    6    7    8
 [3,]    9   10   11   12
 [4,]   13   14   15   16
 [5,]   17   18   19   20
 [6,]   21   22   23   24
 [7,]   25   26   27   28
 [8,]   29   30   31   32
 [9,]   33   34   35   36
[10,]   37   38   39   40

#create reverse matrix
revMtx = yourMtx[,rev(seq_len(ncol(yourMtx)))]

#reverse matrix
>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    4    3    2    1
 [2,]    8    7    6    5
 [3,]   12   11   10    9
 [4,]   16   15   14   13
 [5,]   20   19   18   17
 [6,]   24   23   22   21
 [7,]   28   27   26   25
 [8,]   32   31   30   29
 [9,]   36   35   34   33
[10,]   40   39   38   37
```

Comment: Can you pleas explain what maxIndx is?

Comment: I got it. Thanks. That is what I want. Can you reverse the order of series in rows [1, ], [3, ], [5, ], [7, ], [9, ]?  For example, reversing 1 2 3 4 to 4 3 2 1.

Comment: I've added the maxIndx and column swapping to the solution above

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this looks to be an approach you could use.

```
# generate my series
myseries <- 1:49

# specify number of columns and rows
ncols <- 4
nrows <- 10

# create a matrix with the first ncols*nrows elements and fill by row

mymatrix <- matrix(myseries[1:(ncols*nrows)], 
                   ncol = ncols, nrow = nrows, byrow = TRUE)

 mymatrix
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    2    3    4
 [2,]    5    6    7    8
 [3,]    9   10   11   12
 [4,]   13   14   15   16
 [5,]   17   18   19   20
 [6,]   21   22   23   24
 [7,]   25   26   27   28
 [8,]   29   30   31   32
 [9,]   33   34   35   36
[10,]   37   38   39   40
```